# richfaces rendering for IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, richfaces, rendering

I have developed a demo application a Customer Demographics Wizard in RichFaces3.3.3. Everything is running fine on GoogleChrome and Mozilla Firefox. But facing problem in running the same in IE8. In IE8 wizard's First page is displaying fine, but after clicking the next button while trying to navigate to the next page no form is displaying.

IE8 is displaying error like this :

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
Timestamp: Tue, 11 Dec 2012 11:08:28 UTC

Message: Unknown runtime error
Line: 120
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http: //localhost:8400/BBGUServer/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript.jsf

Can anyone help me out where is the problem.

Thanks in advance..

Following code giving error in IE8 RichFaces3.3.3

Pls see the code given below. Along with this the .java bean files I am not giving, because I dnt think those will be required.

Here start.xhtml is the home page where custStep1.xhtml is loaded. After giving some value in the form when I navigate to the next page by clicking the button "Next" nothing of "custStep2" form is displaying. Only the parent forms drop downs (as you can see those i start.xhtml) are showing. And typically this special problem is occurring in IE8. Everything is running fine in Firefox/Chrome...........

--------------------------------------- Start of start.xhtml

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
        function setSkinValue(skinName)
        {
            Seam.Component.getInstance('skinBean').setSkin(skinName, function()
            {
                Seam.Remoting.log('reloading window');
                window.location.reload(false);
            });
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wizard { width:800px; }
        .wform td { vertical-align:right; }
        .wfcol1 { text-align: right; white-space:nowrap;}
        .s1row td { height:30px; }
        .rich-message { color:red;  }

        .navPanel {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            height:30px;
            margin:0;
            padding:2px;
        }
    </style>
    <head>  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <br/>
    <h:panelGrid width="800px" border="0">
        <a4j:keepAlive beanName="customerBean" />
        <rich:panel styleClass="wizard">
            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="BBGUI Customer Demographics..." />
            </f:facet>
            <h:form id="mainForm" dir="#{customerBean.textDirection}">
                <rich:comboBox
                    id="language" 
                    selectFirstOnUpdate="false"
                    defaultLabel=""
                    value="#{customerBean.languageName}"
                    enableManualInput="false"
                    width="100"> 
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="English"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Arabic"/>
                    <a4j:support event="onselect" reRender="mainForm" action="#{customerBean.changeLanguage}"/>
                </rich:comboBox>
                <br/><br/>
                <rich:comboBox
                    id="theme" 
                    selectFirstOnUpdate="false"
                    defaultLabel="Emerald Town"
                    value="#{skinBean.skin}"
                    enableManualInput="false"
                    width="100"> 
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="emeraldTown"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="blueSky"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="wine"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="japanCherry"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="plain"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="ruby"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="classic"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="laguna"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="deepMarine"/>
                    <a4j:support event="onselect" reRender="mainForm" action="javascript:setSkinValue(this.value);"/>
                </rich:comboBox>
                <rich:comboBox
                    id="country1" 
                    selectFirstOnUpdate="false"
                    defaultLabel=""
                    value="#{accountBean.countryCD}"
                    enableManualInput="false"
                    width="200"> 
                    <f:selectItems value="#{accountBean.countryItems}" />
                </rich:comboBox>
                <br/><br/>
                <a4j:include viewId="#{customerBean.formName}" />
            </h:form>
        </rich:panel>

    </h:panelGrid>
    <br/>
</ui:composition>
```

--------------------------------------- End of start.xhtml

--------------------------------------- End of cust_step1.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE8" />
</head>

    <div style="position:relative;height:140px">
        <h:panelGrid id ="custFrm1" width="750px" columns="4" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

            Customer No: 

            <h:inputText id="customerNo" value="#{customerBean.data.customerno}" size="30" styleClass="inputText"/>

            <h:outputText id="fnamelbl" value="#{customerBean.fnamelbl}:" size="30"/>

            <h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{customerBean.data.firstname}" size="30" styleClass="inputText"/>

            Last Name:

            <h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{customerBean.data.lastname}" size="30" styleClass="inputText"/>

            E-Mail:

            <h:inputText id="eMail" value="#{customerBean.data.emailaddress}" size="30" styleClass="inputText"/>

            Creation Date:

            <rich:calendar id="creationDate" value="#{customerBean.data.creationdate}" size="30"/>

            Country:

            <rich:comboBox
                id="country" 
                selectFirstOnUpdate="false"
                defaultLabel=""
                value="#{customerBean.countryCD}"
                enableManualInput="false"
                width="200" dir="#{customerBean.textDirection}"> 
                <f:selectItems value="#{customerBean.countryItems}" />
                <a4j:support event="onselect" reRender="state"/>
            </rich:comboBox>

            State:

            <rich:comboBox
                id="state" 
                selectFirstOnUpdate="false"
                defaultLabel=""
                value="#{customerBean.stateCD}"
                enableManualInput="false"
                width="200"> 
                <f:selectItems value="#{customerBean.stateItems}" />
                <a4j:support event="onselect" reRender="city"/>
            </rich:comboBox>

            City:

            <rich:comboBox
                id="city" 
                selectFirstOnUpdate="false"
                defaultLabel=""
                value="#{customerBean.cityCD}"
                enableManualInput="false"
                width="200"> 
                <f:selectItems value="#{customerBean.cityItems}" />
            </rich:comboBox>

        </h:panelGrid>
        <BR /><BR />
        <h:panelGroup> 
            <h:outputText value=" " />
            <h:outputText value="Enter Customer No:" />
            <h:inputText id="custNo" value="#{customerBean.custNumberToSearch}" required="true"/>
            <a4j:commandButton id="retrieveButton" value="#{customerBean.retrieveButtonName}" reRender="custFrm1" styleClass="submitButton" action="#{customerBean.actionSearch}"/>
            <a4j:commandButton id="newCustButton" value="#{customerBean.newCustButtonName}" reRender="custFrm1" styleClass="submitButton" action="#{customerBean.actionNewCust}"/>
            <a4j:commandButton id="nextButton" style="float:right" action="next" value="Next &gt;&gt;"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>

    <rich:hotKey key="alt+n"
    handler="#{rich:element('nextButton')}.click();
    event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();
    return false;"/>
    <rich:hotKey selector="#custNo" key="return"
    handler="#{rich:element('retrieveButton')}.click();
    event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();
    return false;"/>

</ui:composition>
```

--------------------------------------- End of cust_step1.xhtml

--------------- Start of cust_step2.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE8" />
</head>

    <div style="position:relative;height:140px">    
        <h:panelGroup>
            <rich:simpleTogglePanel switchType="client" label="Customer Properties">
                <rich:dataTable id="custPropertyData" width="723px" value="#{customerBean.data.customerPropertyList}" 
                                var="custPropData" 
                                columnClasses="10,10,10,10"
                                onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#B5F3FB'"
                                onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.rowBackgroundColor}'"
                                styleClass="table">

                    <rich:column width="220px">
                        <f:facet name="header">Property Id</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText id="propertyID" value="#{custPropData.propertyid}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column width="220px">
                        <f:facet name="header">Property Name</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText id="propertyName" value="#{custPropData.property}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column width="220px">
                        <f:facet name="header">Property Value</f:facet>
                        <h:inputText id="propertyValue" value="#{custPropData.propertyvalue}" />
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:dataTable>
            </rich:simpleTogglePanel>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <BR /><BR />
        <h:panelGroup> 
            <a4j:commandButton value="#{customerBean.saveButtonName}" 
                                styleClass="submitButton" 
                                action="#{customerBean.actionSave}"
                                oncomplete="if(#{customerBean.custSaveFlag == true}) 
                                            {#{rich:component('successPopup')}.show()}
                                            else 
                                            {#{rich:component('errorPopup')}.show()}"/>

            <a4j:commandButton 
                value="#{customerBean.storePropButtonName}" 
                styleClass="submitButton"
                oncomplete="#{rich:component('editPanel')}.show()">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{customerBean}" 
                            target="#{customerBean}"/>  
            </a4j:commandButton>
            <a4j:commandButton id="prevButton" value="&lt;&lt;Previous" style="float:right"  immediate="true" action="previous"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>

     <rich:modalPanel id="successPopup" modal="true" autosized="true" resizeable="false" width="300">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Unicorn" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" >               
            <h:outputText id="idText" value="#{customerBean.saveSuccessfullMsg}" />
            <h:commandButton action="#" onclick="#{rich:component('successPopup')}.hide(); return false;" value="Cancel"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
     </rich:modalPanel>

     <rich:modalPanel id="errorPopup" autosized="true" width="300">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Unicorn" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" >               
            <h:outputText id="idText1" value="#{customerBean.saveErrorMsg}" />
            <h:commandButton action="#" onclick="#{rich:component('errorPopup')}.hide(); return false;" value="Cancel"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
     </rich:modalPanel>

    <rich:hotKey key="alt+b"
    handler="#{rich:element('prevButton')}.click();
    event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();
    return false;"/>

    <rich:modalPanel id="editPanel" autosized="true" width="450">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Save Customer Property" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <rich:componentControl for="editPanel" attachTo="hidelink" operation="hide" event="onclick" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>

<h:form id="form1">
<rich:messages style="color:red;"></rich:messages>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Property Name" />
                        <rich:comboBox
                                id="propname" 
                                selectFirstOnUpdate="false"
                                defaultLabel=""
                                value="#{customerBean.propertyName}"
                                enableManualInput="false"
                                width="250"> 
                            <f:selectItems value="#{customerBean.propertyItems}" />
                        </rich:comboBox>
                        <h:outputText value="Property Value" />
                        <h:inputText id="propval" value="#{customerBean.propertyValue}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <rich:message showSummary="true" showDetail="false" for="propname" />
                </a4j:outputPanel>
                <a4j:commandButton value="Store"
                    action="#{customerBean.actionPropertyStore}"
                    reRender="custPropertyData"
                    oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}) #{rich:component('editPanel')}.hide();"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
    </rich:modalPanel>
</html>
```

--------------- End of cust_step2.xhtml

--------------- Start of faces-Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config version="1.2" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">

    <application>
      <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
    </application>

    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>mypackage.ActionListener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>skinBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>mypackage.SkinBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>        
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>customerBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>mypackage.CustomerBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>accountBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>mypackage.AccountBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
    </managed-bean>

    <navigation-rule> 
        <from-view-id>/Customer/cust_step1.xhtml</from-view-id> 
        <navigation-case> 
            <from-outcome>next</from-outcome> 
            <to-view-id>/Customer/cust_step2.xhtml</to-view-id> 
        </navigation-case> 
    </navigation-rule>  
    <navigation-rule> 
        <from-view-id>/Customer/cust_step2.xhtml</from-view-id> 
        <navigation-case> 
            <from-outcome>previous</from-outcome> 
            <to-view-id>/Customer/cust_step1.xhtml</to-view-id> 
        </navigation-case> 
    </navigation-rule>   
</faces-config>
```

--------------- End of faces-Config.xml

Comment: Where is your code that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
<a4j:commandButton id="nextButton" style="float:right" action="next" value="Next &gt;&gt;"/>
```

replace above with

```
<a4j:commandButton id="nextButton" style="float:right" action="#{customerBean.nextAction}" value="Next"/>
```